# Copy data from one set of tables to another with extra columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any quick way for the below one? instead of generating Insert into Select SQL queries manually one by one for all 500 tables?

I have to copy data from one schema to another. I have about 500 tables. Source and target tables columns are the same, except target has few additional constant columns. Constant columns in target are create_date which is system date, userID which would be a functional ID and another column is ID which is Identity column.

I got the answer from Iain Ward.
Looking for insert into select * query

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results to clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at SQL Server's [SELECT INTO](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp) statement. It let's you select data from an existing table, including any additional data, and insert it into a new one like this:

```
SELECT *, SYSDATETIME(), GETUSERID()
INTO newtable [IN externaldb]
FROM oldtable
WHERE condition;
```

Comment: But you'll need column aliases on those additional columns, no trailing comma, and can't hurt to use `dbo.` prefix in case the caller uses a different default schema and then can't find their tables...

Comment: The problem with using SELECT... INTO (for non-temporary applications) is that you're going to end up with tables in the new schema/database that aren't indexed, and are missing keys and other constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details I can't give a *good* answer, but if you are really just copying from [schema1].[table1] to [schema2].[table1], the easiest thing to do is probably to generate your queries using sys.columns or information_schema.columns.

You could join source & target tables to each other or, if schemas is really identical (except for extra columns) you can just query against schema_1. It's not much more complicated to generate identity_insert statements as needed, either.

The pretty way to do it is to generate one big dynamic sql statement and run it using a set-based query. Less fun is to use a cursor to make you sql. Copying the results of the query to Excel and building your INSERT statements there is easiest if you aren't accustomed to writing safe dynamic sql.